Why robocopy does not copy some files perfectly?

Here, NTUSER.DAT is different between the 2 different files. As if they're not overriden as they're supposed to.
The statement I use is this

robocopy "D:\Users\TeguhProg" "C:\Users\TeguhProg" /e /xo /w:1 /r:1

This should override files that are different right?
Update: It seems that robocopy doesn't overwrite NEWER files. What about if I want robocopy to overwrite ALL files except those with the same size and exact same date?

You cannot overwrite NTUSER.DAT anyway, it's HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry and as such always in use.

"What about if I want robocopy to overwrite ALL files except those with the same size and exact same date?" - That's the default behaviour

What do the logs of the transfer process say? Do they tell you there is a problem with the source file, or with the destination?

Robocopy may not be copying ntuser.dat because the file is in active use and locked, not because it is newer than the destination.
If you are trying to backup the user profile, you may wish to use the /B argument, which instructs Robocopy to use its Backup mode and allows it to copy files it normally doesn't have access to.
